# Beamer and Polyglossa font command compatibility?

Tags: beamer, polyglossia

The following document works fine when using document class `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{SBL Greek}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
A greek word \textgreek{αταραξία} and a hebrew word \texthebrew{קֹהֶלֶת}

\end{document}
```

But then when I switch over to Beamer. It seems to begin to ignore the fonts (and we end up with blank characters instead of the greek or hebrew:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{SBL Greek}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First}
A greek word \textgreek{αταραξία} and a hebrew word \texthebrew{קֹהֶלֶת}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Note that we can add `\setsansfont{Arial}` to the beamer sample, and it seems to globally tell beamer to use the `Arial` font, instead of the Hebrew/Greek fonts that have been specified:

[image]

Comment: Your MWE has no `\textgreek` around the greek text. Your screenshot has. Which version do you use?

Comment: I was trying several different things. Whatever makes it work. I have amended the MWE to be consistent.

Comment: I cannot test as I don't have the fonts you use, but can you try `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts`?

Comment: Using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` with `\setsansfont{Arial}` does nothing. Using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` without `\setsansfont{Arial}`, gets us back to `\texthebrew{}` and `\textgreek{}` showing blank text (It seems the default fonts for beamer don't contain characters for other languages)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}{SBL Hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}{SBL Greek}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First}

A greek word \textgreek{αταραξία} and a hebrew word \texthebrew{קֹהֶלֶת}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, why is the serif font specification necessary? When I do this in a normal class (not beamer) with XeLaTeX, I can load the new font family without the sans serif and it works. From the polyglossia documentation (section 4), it looks like you should only need the \greekfontsf if you use \textgreeksf, which is not the case in your example. Does beamer force sans serif or something?

Comment: @Paul (sorry for the late reply, I seem to have missed your comment at the time) Yes, beamer uses sans serif by default.